# Error using numpy.ctypeslib.load_library

Tags: python, c++, linker

I have this `prog.cpp` program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I have this `prog.py` program that should load `main` into a python function:

```
import subprocess
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct

subprocess.call(['gcc', '-Wall','-c', '-fPIC', 'prog.cpp', '-o', 'prog.o'])
subprocess.call(['gcc', 'prog.o', '-shared', '-o', 'lib_prog.so'])

lib = npct.load_library('lib_prog', '.')
fun = getattr(lib,'main')
fun()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 7, in <module>
    lib = npct.load_library('lib_prog', '.')
(...)
OSError: /my_dir/lib_prog.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4cout
```

My program seems identical to any example on how to use `numpy.ctypeslib.load_library`. Would someone have any insights on what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a linker error. You have to load your standard library first. (Or, you can declare it as a dependency using -lstdc++ in your linker command line)

Comment: What is my standard library?

Comment: Your standard library is the library that provides the symbols from the `std` namespace. It's probably libstdc++, though it might be different on your system.

Comment: This is not a python error though, so please retag it with appropriate flags (this is related to python at best). It's a linker problem

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. 
Do you mean that the problem is in the line `using namespace std;`?

Comment: I tried changing it to `using namespace libstdc++;` but it wont work

Comment: The name of the standard library is correct. `using namespace std;` is just fine. May I suggest you to read up on compilation/linking first? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work), I hope it will clear some of your confusion up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [here](http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/dll-in-c-for-python/) that all one need to do is to add `extern "C"` before `int main...`

May that be of help for anyone some years from now.